# Linking to man page sections?

Tags: documentation, html, manpage

### Online man pages in HTML with section anchors?

It would be good to have an online version of the Ubuntu man pages with direct links into subsections. That would allow to point someone to the relevant documentation in many cases - for example in answers of various StackExchange sites.

I will describe how a full solution might look, and in which ways that would be useful.
I do not think a complete solution is available somewhere,so the question is

**Which partial solutions exist today?**

For example, somehow systematic ways to search into the man pages, instead of linking, would be a partial solution.

The man pages at [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/) solve most of the problem, but they do not have anchors on the headings or sections.

That means, if I want to point to the section "Parameter Expansion" in 
[`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) online, I have to use

> See "Parameter Expansion" in [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html%20%22man%20page%20of%20'bash'%20at%20manpages.ubuntu.com%22)
>   [...and use your browser to search for "Parameter Expansion"]

This opens the bash man page at the top, as one long web page.

In the shell, I can say

> See `man bash | less "+/Parameter Expansion"`

which jumps to the right place at startup.

It would be really helpful to have link anchors named like the headings they point to. Anchors named by some kind of index number would still help, but require a manual lookup on the actual web page to use it.

As it is not difficult on HTML level to add anchors to headings, I'm sure such man pages exist;
But is there a collection of the **Ubuntu man pages with anchors** online somewhere, or at least a good subset?

### Example code

The header of section "Parameter Expansion" from
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash
which kind-of-redirects to
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html

```html
       [ ... ]
       tildes in assignments to <b>PATH</b>, <b>MAILPATH</b>,  and  <b>CDPATH</b>,  and  the  shell
       assigns the expanded value.

   <b>Parameter</b> <b>Expansion</b>
       The `<b>$</b>' character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution,
       or arithmetic expansion.  The parameter name or symbol to  be  expanded
       [ ... ]
```

To be able to link directly to this section, we need something like:

```html
       [ ... ]
       tildes in assignments to <b>PATH</b>, <b>MAILPATH</b>,  and  <b>CDPATH</b>,  and  the  shell
       assigns the expanded value.

   <a href="#ParameterExpansion"><b>Parameter</b> <b>Expansion</b></a>
       The `<b>$</b>' character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution,
       or arithmetic expansion.  The parameter name or symbol to  be  expanded
       [ ... ]
```

This adds one tag to the HTML code, and one attribute, the section name without spaces:

`<b>Parameter</b> <b>Expansion</b>`
`<a href="#ParameterExpansion"><b>Parameter</b> <b>Expansion</b></a>`

**Now, we can link to the section like**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash#ParameterExpansion
or even
[manpages.ubuntu.com/bash#ParameterExpansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash#ParameterExpansion)

which uses a foot note and is is written like
[manpages.ubuntu.com/bash#ParameterExpansion][6]

---

### Use of other reference documents

In many cases, there are alternative reference documents available, appart from the man page. These often have a good link structure that is used to link from a table of content to the sections, just what we need.
But this **does not solve the general problem**, as there is no common way to find whether/where such a document existst, and to make use of the link structure.

For the bash example used above, the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) could be used as an individual solution looked up manually:

[Bash Reference Manual section Shell-Parameter-Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
written as
[Bash Reference Manual section Shell-Parameter-Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

### Proposed implementation

To propose actually implementing this idea at **manpages.ubuntu.com**,
I filed a closely related bug/enhancement request on the associated project "ubuntu-manpage-repository":
[launchpad #1355271: Use HTML a tags to allow external links to subsections of man pages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository/+bug/1355271)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Please file a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository) for this.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Sure, that's the obvious part ;) Actually, manpages.ubuntu.com liiks like a very clean implementation, but I remember it's done by a single developer. Let's see...

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Here it is: [launchpad #1355271: Use HTML a tags to allow external links to subsections of man pages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository/+bug/1355271)

Comment: Not sure if this queston is supposed to be here, or Meta Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlaaAli *Meta* is only for questions about *Ask Ubuntu*, not about the Ubuntu project or other Ubuntu-related websites.

Comment: @AlaaAli The question how to best make use of it for Ask Ubuntu when we actually have it would be for Meta Ask Ubuntu

Comment: I don't know if they were present before and I simply didn't notice, but there's a sidebar with anchor links to the sections in Ubuntu Manpages now. Unfortunately linking to them doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: I use the shell commands method, but rather than a pipeline I give a single command with an environment variable set.  See `LESS='+/LESS[[:space:]]*Options' man less`

Comment: By the way, I wrote a very similar question here: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3960/135943

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is, it's http://man.cx/. It aims to have all man pages in one site, also in multiple languages. The anchors are unfortunately not named, but numbered: for example http://man.cx/printf#heading1 will take you to the first heading of the `printf` man page. Still I think it's better than without anchors ;)

PS. Add the site to your search engines, then you can simply type `man printf` in your address bar, and it will take you to the correct page, super awesome!

Comment: Great idea for the browser integration as search engine!

Comment: Downvote without comment?

Comment: unfortunately, site seems corrupt: page missing and lots of ADs

Comment: That is unfortunate, http://man.he.net/ still works as an alternative!

Answer (score 2):

On [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18151/how-to-follow-links-in-linux-man-pages), there are ways described to **use the offline manpages as hypertext** too. The easiest way for me seems w3mman, which is part of the package `w3m`, so:

`sudo apt-get install w3m`

When you opened a man page, f.e. `w3mman man`, you can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate to the next link. (Other man-typical keyboard shortcuts work the same: scrolling, searching, quitting :-)

To turn off quit confirmation (like `man` behaves):

- edit `~/.w3m/config`

  - if not existing: `cp /etc/w3m/config ~/.w3m/`
- set `confirm_qq 0`

To replace the normal *man* command:

- edit `~/.bashrc`

  - add `alias man='w3mman'`
- `source ~/.bashrc`

Now `man <some command>` will use w3mman instead of the normal man :) I like it this way. Thanks for asking! :)

Answer (score 0):

8 years later,
Linking man pages with section anchors is still not easy today.

The archlinux man page seems to be the only one I known

### archlinux man

has some anchors, but not enough

a demo link:
https://man.archlinux.org/man/bash.1.en#extglob

### gnu man

has some anchors

demo link:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Indexes
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching